# No me carga la imagen en mi galería

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagen, carga

Necesito ayuda, estoy creando una **galería de imágenes** y quiero *pre-visualizar* la imagen pero me sale un error de que no carga la imagen, este es el error que me sale:

[image: error que muestra la consola del navegador]

No se si de pronto no es la forma correcta de cargar la imagen.

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="new_image" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
   <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Image</label>
  </div>
```

---

```
function save_image(){
    if($("#new_image").val()!="" && $("#title_img").val()!="" && $("#_url").val()!=""  && $('select[id=category]').val()!="Choose.."){
        
        var _img=document.getElementById("new_image").files[0].name; 
        var _title=$("#title_img").val();
        var _url=$("#_url").val();
        var _category=$('select[id=category]').val();
        console.log('entro');
        createPreview(_img,_title,_url,_category);
    }else{
        $('#alert_check').show()
        setTimeout(function () {
             $('#alert_check').hide();
            }, 3000);
        ;
    }
}

function createPreview(img,title,url,category){

    console.log(img);
    console.log(title);
    console.log(url);
    console.log(category);

    var new_img=$('<div class="box ' + category + '"><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+img+'" alt="'+category+'"></a><div class="tit"><h3>'+title+'</h3></div></div>');
     $(new_img).insertBefore("#first_photo");
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo HTML adicional que se referencia en el codigo `#url` y `#title_img`. Como obtienes el valor de `#url`?

Comment: Al parecer estas tratando de cargar una imagen con una URL de sistema de archivos local `file://`. Si las imagenes se cargan solo con el `<input type=file>` no necesitas incluir una URL, se puede obtener del archivo cargado.

Comment: Por razones de seguridad, los navegadores bloquearán acceso a la imagen por su ruta en disco, necesitas usar `fileReader`, aquí un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Hola! lo de la url es porque necesito incluir un link en mi html

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haces posteriormente con la imagen y el enlace? Porque no creo que te sean de utilidad si no guardas los datos (e imagen) primero.

Comment: es que solo necesito  la previsualizar la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que los compañeros estoy confundido respecto a qué valor tiene **$("#_url")**. Sin embargo, si solo te interesa mostrar una vista previa de la imagen que el usuario acaba de cargar, lo puedes hacer así:

```js
function previewFile(input){
    var file = $("input[type=file]").get(0).files[0];

    if(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(){
          crearVistaPrevia(reader.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

function crearVistaPrevia(img) {
   var imagen = '<img src="' + img + '">';
   $("#vistaPrevia").append(imagen);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
    <input type="file" name="photo" onchange="previewFile(this);" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
</p>
<div id="vistaPrevia"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!! esto me ayudo demasiado!!!!

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado, para eso estamos aquí. Si consideras que mi respuesta resolvió tu duda, la podrías marcar como respuesta por favor? Saludos!